# How to use MAPCAR to implement REMOVE-IF

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How can I use the `MAPCAR` function to implement a function equivalent to `REMOVE-IF`, *non-recursively* in Common Lisp?

Comment: You can't do this with `mapcar`. `mapcar` returns a list of the results of calling the function with each element of the input list. There's no way for it to leave one of them out if the element matches the filter function.

Comment: `(apply #'append (mapcar #'(lambda(x)(if (= x 17) nil (list x))) (list 1 7 17 71)))` ==> `(1 7 71)`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible with `MAPCAR`, because it always returns a list of the same length as the input (and you want a shorter list, if some of the input elements satisfy the predicate.)

But it is possible with the related function `MAPCAN`.  If you

1. Apply the predicate to each element `X`.

   - If `X` satisfies the predicate, substitute `(X)`

     If `X` does not satisfy the predicate, substitute `NIL`
2. Concatenate the resulting lists

then you will have a list containing the elements that did not satisfy the predicate, as required.

`MAPCAN` will combine these operations, given a function that implements step #1.

Example:

```
(defun list-if-not (pred)
  (lambda (x) (if (funcall pred x) nil (list x))))

(defun my-remove-if (pred lst)
  (mapcan (list-if-not pred) lst))

(my-remove-if #'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

==> `(1 3 5)`

`MAPCAR` alone cannot do this, though you can combine it with `NCONC` (or `APPEND`) for the same result:

```
(defun my-remove-if (pred lst)
  (apply #'nconc (mapcar (list-if-not pred) lst)))
```